# My meeting no longer in my calendar, but is in my attendees

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I have a recurring monthly meeting I set up, which seems to have disappeared from my calendar. However, it is obviously still in everyone else's as I'm still getting declines and acceptances.

I have set up a new meeting going forward, but can't remove the original from everyone's calendars as I don't have access to it any longer!

Any ideas on how I can get it back? I don't see it in either my deleted items or recover deleted items...

Comment: You can't get it back.

Comment: So they will all have to delete their invites separately? Seems crazy!

Comment: 2021 and this is still an issue. I cannot see the event in which I am the organizer!

Answer (score 3):

My problem was I tried canceling a meeting but didn't want to send out a cancellation email. It turns out you can't do that, and all that got accomplished was that I deleted myself, the host from the meeting. Everyone else was still on it. So, I had to have one of the attendees send me the meeting in the form of an ICS file, then I had to import it into my calendar, and then cancel it again from there.

Answer (score 1):

It happens when you cancel a meeting and you choose not to send the update to the attendees.

Try these two, see if it works:

1. Go to your trash, find the calendar that's deleted and undelete it.
2. Can you have one person forward you the invite. See if it reappears in your calendar. And if it does, then cancel the meeting, and remember to send the update to the attendees. 
   Good luck.

Comment: I tried both, and even the fw meeting does not appear in my calendar.

Answer (score 1):

I somehow solved this issue. I asked my colleague to forward the meeting to me. In respond tab I forwarded the meeting to my other Email. After that I can see the meeting in my calendar.

Comment: That trick solved the proplem, in my cas i was sending it to myself

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to solve this in my situation. The invite I sent yesterday was not on my calendar but was on recipients calendar.
Locate the calendar invite in your 'Deleted' folder, then grab it and drag it onto the 'calendar' icon in the outlook shortcut bar. The invite will show back up onto your calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Open the delivery failure email in your inbox, and in toolbar you will have resend/send again option.
You can correct the recipient list here by removing few unwanted email IDs or limit it based on allowed receipient number and click on resend.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I sent the invite moments before my enterprise password expired (due to WFH I don't get the renewal notices). The calendar invite appeared in the attendees calendar but not in mine. I only looked at my calendar and saw the notice wasn't there, so I sent a 2nd meeting. Since the 1st didn't appear in my calendar I couldn't send a cancelation. I tried syncing online outlook and app, I tried to fwd the notice to myself in an ICS file, that didn't work either.. I tried all stated above including having an attendee send a proposed time change and when I received that the options I normally would use as the organizer i saw they were greyed out. THE ONLY SOLUTION WAS TO SEND A MANUAL EMAIL AND ASK EACH PERSON TO DELETE THE CALENDAR INVITE MANUALLY.

I hope a fix comes up for this but until then this is all I have to help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by selecting having another attendee forward the meeting invite to the user, then selecting 'meeting options' from the invite.
From there I was able to add another user as a 'co-organiser' and have that person send out the cancellation.

Answer (score -1):

Often the reason for missing Outlook items is a custom view.

If you do a search on the subject you may find it is just hidden.

There is information here about views.

http://www.outlook-tips.net/beginner-user/reset-the-view-in-outlook/

As a last resort you can reset all views with the /cleanviews switch.

Answer (score -1):

My situation was similar: I tried to cancel a recurring meeting from the Outlook client and the meeting just disappeared when I clicked "Cancel Meeting" (it usually gives you the ability to edit a message).

When I checked my Sent Items, no cancellation had been sent, but I started getting messages from Outlook saying, "Outlook sent a message on behalf of "an attendee" that the meeting is still in their calendar, but no longer present in yours".

The meeting was completely deleted from my Outlook, yet everyone else still had it on their calendars as no cancellation was actually sent.

To resolve this, I went to OWA (Outlook Web Access), where luckily the meeting was still on my calendar, and I was able to send a proper cancellation from OWA.

Answer (score -1):

I also had the issue. I was able to fix it by having a colleague forward the meeting back to me, then opening said forwarded invitation on the outlook app on my phone (iOS) and I had a "Add" option at the bottom of the screen.
I now have all futur occurences also.